# Combine file names with folders based on commn value in CSV

Tags: powershell

Looking for some guidance on how I can match the files to folders based on a common value in both items.
I have a .csv file that is in the following format:

```
Files                   Paths
-----                   -----
file_JPG_1.zip          C:\path\to\JPG
file_GIF_1.zip          C:\path\to\GIF
file_PNG_1.zip          C:\path\to\JPG
file_PNG_2.zip          C:\path\to\GIF
file_PNG_3.zip          C:\path\to\JPG
file_BMP_2.zip          C:\path\to\GIF
file_JPG_3.zip
file_GIF_3.zip
file_PNG_4.zip
file_PNG_5.zip
file_PNG_6.zip
file_BMP_3.zip
```

I have a complete list of 'Files' but not a complete list of 'Paths'.

What I am trying to do is to  in the 'Paths' columns of the .csv based on the file type that is present in both the file name and the folder path.
So basically, any file name that contains 'JPG' will be have the corresponding path that contains 'JPG' pasted into the 'Paths' column.

The end result of that I'm looking for should be:

```
Files                   Paths
-----                   -----
file_JPG_1.zip          C:\path\to\JPG
file_GIF_1.zip          C:\path\to\GIF
file_PNG_1.zip          C:\path\to\PNG
file_PNG_2.zip          C:\path\to\PNG
file_PNG_3.zip          C:\path\to\PNG
file_BMP_2.zip          C:\path\to\BMP
file_JPG_3.zip          C:\path\to\JPG
file_GIF_3.zip          C:\path\to\GIF
file_PNG_4.zip          C:\path\to\PNG
file_PNG_5.zip          C:\path\to\PNG
file_PNG_6.zip          C:\path\to\PNG
file_BMP_3.zip          C:\path\to\BMP
```

The files will be sorted in (roughly) the order shown above.
I am able to get the values from both of these columns on their own, but I can't seem to figure out how I can actually accomplish this.

Any tips/ideas/suggestions on how I can achieve this?
Thank you!!

** **Update: See below for clarification** **

Ok, I'm going to clarify my question as best I can.

I get a list of files and the destinations they need to be extracted to via email.
What I am doing with this email is taking out all of the text and just keeping the file names + the destination path the files need to be extracted to and storing that in a .CSV file that will be processed by another script.
The format of the mail is along the lines of:

```
1. Extract 3452_JPG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - JPG.ZIP to C:\Images\Graphics\JPG\fdr_435
2. Extract 3452_GIF_FDR_435_DRF1712 - GIF.ZIP to C:\Images\Graphics\GIF\fdr_435
3. Extract 3452_PNG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - PNG.ZIP to C:\Images\Graphics\PNG\fdr_435
etc...
```

Using the above as an example, I am able to generate the .CSV file correctly, so I will end up with:

```
Files                                Paths
-----                                -----
3452_JPG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - JPG.ZIP   C:\Images\Graphics\JPG\fdr_435
3452_GIF_FDR_435_DRF1712 - GIF.ZIP   C:\Images\Graphics\GIF\fdr_435
3452_PNG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - PNG.ZIP   C:\Images\Graphics\PNG\fdr_435
etc...
```

The problem comes around when .Z0x (these are WinRar SFX files) are listed in the email, as the email would then read:

```
1. Extract 3452_JPG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - JPG.ZIP to C:\Images\Graphics\JPG\fdr_435
-The following will be automatically extracted:
3452_JPG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - JPG.Z01
3452_JPG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - JPG.Z02
etc...
```

What I am left with is a .CSV that now looks like this:

```
Files                                                        Paths
-----                                                        -----
3452_JPG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - JPG.ZIP                           C:\Images\Graphics\JPG\fdr_435
3452_JPG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - JPG.Z01                           C:\Images\Graphics\PNG\fdr_435
3452_PNG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - PNG.ZIP                           C:\Images\Graphics\BMP\fdr_435
3452_PNG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - PNG.Z01                           C:\Images\Graphics\GIF\fdr_435
3452_PNG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - PNG.Z02                           C:\Images\Graphics\RAW\FDR
3452_BMP_FDR_435_DRF1712 - BMP.ZIP                           C:\Images\Graphics\ICO\fdr_435
3452_BMP_FDR_435_DRF1712 - BMP.Z01                           C:\Images\Graphics\ICO\fdr_120
3452_BMP_FDR_435_DRF1712 - BMP.Z02                           C:\Images\Graphics\ICO\fdr_120
3452_BMP_FDR_435_DRF1712 - BMP.Z03                             
3452_GIF_FDR_435_DRF1712 - GIF.ZIP                   
3463_RAW_FDR_DRF1712 - RAW.ZIP                               
3457_ICO_fdr_435_STC1712 - ICO.ZIP                     
3456_ICO_FDR_435_DRF1712_ICO VO - ICO.ZIP          
3456_ICO_FDR_435_DRF1712_ICO VO - ICO_SET 2.ZIP
```

As you can see, the paths for the files no longer line up.
The idea is that I want to fill the paths column with the proper paths the .Z0x files are going to be extracted to as well.
So the end result should be a .CSV that looks like:

```
Files                                                        Paths
-----                                                        -----
3452_JPG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - JPG.ZIP                           C:\Images\Graphics\JPG\fdr_435
3452_JPG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - JPG.Z01                           C:\Images\Graphics\JPG\fdr_435
3452_PNG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - PNG.ZIP                           C:\Images\Graphics\PNG\fdr_435
3452_PNG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - PNG.Z01                           C:\Images\Graphics\PNG\fdr_435
3452_PNG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - PNG.Z02                           C:\Images\Graphics\PNG\fdr_435
3452_BMP_FDR_435_DRF1712 - BMP.ZIP                           C:\Images\Graphics\BMP\fdr_435
3452_BMP_FDR_435_DRF1712 - BMP.Z01                           C:\Images\Graphics\BMP\fdr_435
3452_BMP_FDR_435_DRF1712 - BMP.Z02                           C:\Images\Graphics\BMP\fdr_435
3452_BMP_FDR_435_DRF1712 - BMP.Z03                           C:\Images\Graphics\BMP\fdr_435
3452_GIF_FDR_435_DRF1712 - GIF.ZIP                           C:\Images\Graphics\GIF\fdr_435
3463_RAW_FDR_DRF1712 - RAW.ZIP                               C:\Images\Graphics\RAW\FDR
3457_ICO_fdr_435_STC1712 - ICO.ZIP                           C:\Images\Graphics\ICO\fdr_435
3456_ICO_FDR_435_DRF1712_ICO VO - ICO.ZIP                    C:\Images\Graphics\ICO\fdr_120
3456_ICO_FDR_435_DRF1712_ICO VO - ICO_SET 2.ZIP              C:\Images\Graphics\ICO\fdr_120
```

With the code provided, I end up with my Paths column looking like this:

```
Paths
-----
C:\Images\Graphics\JPG
C:\Images\Graphics\JPG
C:\Images\Graphics\PNG
C:\Images\Graphics\PNG
C:\Images\Graphics\PNG
C:\Images\Graphics\BMP
C:\Images\Graphics\BMP
C:\Images\Graphics\BMP
C:\Images\Graphics\BMP
C:\Images\Graphics\GIF
C:\Images\Graphics\RAW
C:\Images\Graphics\ICO
C:\Images\Graphics\ICO
C:\Images\Graphics\ICO
```

If this is still unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Are the file names actually formatted like that, where it is the word 'file', the type of file, and an iteration, joined by underscores?

Comment: Why are the last two in the ICO\fdr_120 folder? Nothing in their file name suggests that they should be. Assuming that is an error and either the file name should be 3456_ICO_FDR_120, or they should belong in ICO\fdr_435, I have something that'll do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have folders for each kind of file all located in the same place and your files names are all formatted like that, like in your example, this is really easy. This answer uses the `.Split()` method, and a calculated property.

```
$CSVData = Import-Csv data.csv | Select Files,@{l='Paths';e={'C:\Path\To\' + $_.Files.Split('_')[1]}}
```

If things are not as simple as in your example we can work with that, we just need a more accurate example and explanation.

**Edit:** Ok, looking at the updated CSV file I see that you have a list of potential paths in one column, and a list of files in the other. What I would suggest is to get the list of paths into another variable. Then build a hashtable with those paths as the key, and split the path on backslash and underscore (underscore because the files are underscore delimited). Now loop through the files, and for each one split on underscores. Compare that to the split paths, and take the path with the most matches.

Here's the script that'll do that:

```
#Import the CSV
$CSV = Import-Csv $CSVPath
#Capture all the unique paths
$AllPaths = $CSV.Paths | Select -Unique
#Make an empty hashtable
$AllPathsSplit = @{}
#Loop through paths, and add each to the hashtable as a key, with the path split on '\' and '_' as the value
$AllPaths |%{$AllPathsSplit.Add($_,($_ -split '\\|_'))}

#Loop through files
ForEach($File in $CSV){
    #Set the path by looking at each item in the hashtable and finding the one with the most matches to the file split on underscores
    $File.Paths = $AllPaths|Sort {(Compare-Object ($File.Files -split '_') -DifferenceObject $AllPathsSplit[$_] -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual -PassThru).Count} -Descending |Select -First 1
}
```

And here's the output:

```
PS C:\Users\TMTech> $CSV

Files                                           Paths                         
-----                                           -----                         
3452_JPG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - JPG.ZIP              C:\Images\Graphics\JPG\fdr_435
3452_JPG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - JPG.Z01              C:\Images\Graphics\JPG\fdr_435
3452_PNG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - PNG.ZIP              C:\Images\Graphics\PNG\fdr_435
3452_PNG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - PNG.Z01              C:\Images\Graphics\PNG\fdr_435
3452_PNG_FDR_435_DRF1712 - PNG.Z02              C:\Images\Graphics\PNG\fdr_435
3452_BMP_FDR_435_DRF1712 - BMP.ZIP              C:\Images\Graphics\BMP\fdr_435
3452_BMP_FDR_435_DRF1712 - BMP.Z01              C:\Images\Graphics\BMP\fdr_435
3452_BMP_FDR_435_DRF1712 - BMP.Z02              C:\Images\Graphics\BMP\fdr_435
3452_BMP_FDR_435_DRF1712 - BMP.Z03              C:\Images\Graphics\BMP\fdr_435
3452_GIF_FDR_435_DRF1712 - GIF.ZIP              C:\Images\Graphics\GIF\fdr_435
3463_RAW_FDR_DRF1712 - RAW.ZIP                  C:\Images\Graphics\RAW\FDR    
3457_ICO_fdr_435_STC1712 - ICO.ZIP              C:\Images\Graphics\ICO\fdr_435
3456_ICO_FDR_435_DRF1712_ICO VO - ICO.ZIP       C:\Images\Graphics\ICO\fdr_435
3456_ICO_FDR_435_DRF1712_ICO VO - ICO_SET 2.ZIP C:\Images\Graphics\ICO\fdr_435
```

I am assuming that your desired output has a mistake for the last 2 items, because there is nothing in the file name to indicate that the path should be ICO\fdr_120

Comment: This is almost what I was after! The filenames themselves are simple, they do use leading and trailing underscores. The only thing I forgot to mention is that the folder paths contain a directory after the file type (JPG, PNG, etc...), so for example, the directory would look like:

`C:\folder\JPG\abc_123`

`C:\folder\JPG\abc_456`

`C:\folder\PNG\abc_123`

`C:\folder\GIF\abc_123`

...and so on.

This folder structure would already be defined in the source CSV file.
I would still need to preserve the folder structure after the file type. Make sense?

Comment: Can you please update your question to give a more accurate CSV example then please?

Comment: I've updated the question to hopefully clear up my question a bit more.

Comment: This is perfect, almost like artwork! The ICO\fdr_120 was the correct path, but there was a typo in the filename that was delivered in the email which explains that. Thanks for this!!